# How can i remove space in the variable which got from some web with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, variables, beautifulsoup, space

[image: string]

```
price =rawdata[2].text

print("-",price,"-")
```

Comment: try using the function `strip`

Answer (score 0):

If spaces are heading or trailing spaces then you can use

```
price.strip()
```

but you have "-" as your first and last character. Therefore you can use the following

```
price.replace(" ","")
```

which will replace all spaces with nothing (remove spaces).

Comment: I got it Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip()`

Example:

```
x = "hell o"
print(x.strip())
```

Output:

```
hello
```